# the set of extendable p.c. functions is not N

Tags: computer-science, computability, recursion

Show that the set 
$Ext:= \big\{x\in N : \varphi_{x}$ is extendable to a total recursive function  $\big\}$ 
 is not equal to the set of non negative integers $N$.

Would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: have you heard of *recursively inseparable* sets? If $A, B$ are r.e. and disjoint, there's a natural *partial* computable function $f$ given by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$, $f(x)=1$ for $x\in B$, and $f(x)\uparrow$ for $x\not\in A\cup B$.

- Suppose $f$ can be extended to a total recursive function. Show that there is a **recursive** set $C$ with $A\subseteq C$ and $C\cap B=\emptyset$ (such a $C$ is a *separator* for $A$ and $B$).
- Show that there is a pair of disjoint r.e. sets $A$ and $B$ which are **recursively inseparable** (that is, no such $C$ exists). HINT$^2$: consider the theorems of Peano arithmetic . . .

---

This is merely one approach. Another approach comes via *diagonalization*.

Consider the following function $g$: $g(x)=\varphi_x(x)+1$. Intuitively, $g$ should diagonalize out of the set of partial recursive functions. Unfortunately, of course, there's no reason we can't have $g=\varphi_x$ for some $x$ - all that we'd need is $\varphi_x(x)\uparrow$.

Do you see why this $g$ can't be extended to a total computable function?

Comment: Could you please explain why this function $g$ can't be extended to a totalcomputable function?

Comment: @Aref Suppose it could be. Let $\varphi_y$ be a total function extending $g$. Then what's $\varphi_y(y)$?